# Creating a if else in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a if/else verification in prolog, but actually i cant pass a parenthesis as a predicate "parameter", the code follows bellow

```
s(Z):- si(X), vp(Y), append(X,Y,Z).
si(Z):- i(X), openParent(Y), append(X,Y,Z).
vp(Z):- cond(X), closeParent(Y), append(X,Y,Z).

i([if]).
openParent(['(']).
closeParent([')']).
cond([cond]).

%running s(X) to see all the possibilities:
%expected : if, (, cond, )
%output : if, '(', cond, ')'
```

On openParent and closeParent i want to pass the parenthesis without quotes, but if do, the execution gives an error.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense right now. Look for [DCGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dcg). It's the tool you're searching, available in most Prologs, and surely in SWISH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog constants start with lower case letters, if you want to have constants that do not follow this convention you have to escape them via `'('`. To distinguish them from the reserved keywords the escaping needs to stay in place. This is still better than C for example, where `int void = 0` is a forbidden statement and there's no escaping to write it down.

You might also want to think about what your predicate is supposed to do. A unary predicate like `s/1` can only tell you if the term you pass fulfils your requirements. If you want to create something out of it (for example an evaluation of the if-then-else) you would need two arguments `s(Ast, Evaluation)`.

Another observation is that you are already working on a symbolic representation: your code produces e.g. a list `[if, '(', Cond, ')', TrueBranch]` where `if` only takes one space (a string would use two). But if the representation is symbolic, why not just represent parenthesis as `lparen` and `rparen`? Or even better, `if` has only two / three arguments, why not represent it as `if(Cond, TrueBranch)` and `if(Cond, TrueBranch, ElseBranch)`?